# Retrieving data from isolated storage into viewmodel

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, observablecollection, isolatedstorage, databound

I am having a serious mental block here and am in departate need for some help. I am using the Windows Phone Databound Application as the starting point of my project and am reasonably happy with how the model,viewmodel and view interact.

My issue is that the data used in the example is created at run time and added to the ObservableCollection object.  My understanding is that the creation of the new ItemViewModel objects and the subsequent adding of them to the ObservableCollection fires the equavalent to the NotifyPropertyChanged events which ensure that the bindings on the view all refresh. If my explanation is incorrect then I would welcome any thoughts.

Now, the runtime generation of data is useless in most real-world examples and as such I need to serialize the data to isolated storage. This I have done and can successfully save and load my ObservableCollection object.

My problem arises when I load the data from IsolatedStorage and then assign the returned ObservableCollection to the Items object in the view model.

```
    public void LoadData()
    {
        App.Measurements = Serialization.Read<measurements>(App.MEASUREMENTS);
        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }
```

App.MEASUREMENTS in simply a global variable that contains the file name to be used in IsolatedStorage.

The above code retrieves the data and assigns it to the Items ObservableCollection but the UI is not updated.  If I replace the code above with:

```
    public void LoadData()
    {
        foreach (measurement m in App.Measurements.WeightMeasurements)
        {
            this.Items.Add(m);
        }
        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }
```

and iterate throught the retrieved collection and add a new ItemViewModel collection to the Items collection then everything updates on the UI correctly.

My xaml has the correct bindings and the DataContext is set correctly too.

I have tried numersou ways trying to solve this but I can't believe that the only way is to iterate through the entire loaded collection adding it to the Items collections just some the event will fire!

Any thoughts most welcomed.

Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to the bottom of it in the end. It was to do with the definition of the ObservableCollection.  OUt of the box it looks like this

```
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
```

However, the NotifyPropertyChanged only gets fired when the property is defined as such:

```
    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        private set
        {
            if(_items != value)
                _items = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
```

Items implemented INotifyPropertyChanged but it was never getting called when the Items object was being assigned to.

Everything works just as expected now and there is no need to iterate through the loaded collection and add it to the Items ObservableCollection.

Comment: This was my first question and my answer. You said you were already doing this.

Comment: @Matt My interpretation of your response didn't lead me to my ultimate conclusion, although in retrospect your question contained a pointer to the final solution. The properties witinh the class that **Item** was instantiated from did implement NPC, however, it is now obvious to me that it is insufficient to have just the properties of the class implement NPC, and the property that implements the class (object) also needs to raise a NPC event to have the UI updated.  Thanks again for sticking with me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on `Items`?

As an ObservableCollection it will handle calling INPC on individual items within the collection when they're changed but you still need to handle this for the property itself.

Comment: I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on the Items class but the issue appears to be that the ObservableCollection<Items> doesn't fire the CollectionChanged event when the deserialized collection gets assigned to the Items Collection.

Comment: @Jason can you provide a repro project to confirm this?

Comment: shall I email it to you directly? Don't really want it posted here! Shal I use your email address from your website?

Comment: please let me know where to send it to. Thanks, Jason.

Comment: Create a project which recreates your issue in the simplest possible way and post a link here. I can't promise to do anything with something you send me via email. Posting it here means others may be able to provide answers or benefit from the solution when found.

Comment: Project available from [link](http://www.myaspdevelopment.com/wp7/WP7SampleApp.rar). The LoadData method in MainViewModel creates and adds new ItemViewModel objects to the collection. The collection is then serialized to IsolatedStorage. Items is then cleared. Line 84 is what I expect to be able to do but the UI is not updated. Lines 88 to 92 are my work around to update the UI. Is the iteration really necessary?  ANy thoughts welcomed.

Comment: Would have been nice to know that you were using the 7.1 tools. I just downloaded your sample on a machine which isn't running the mango beta and couldn't open it. :(

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that.  The Mango thing wasn't at the root of my issue (at least I didn't believe it to be) and as such I simply neglected to mention it.  Thanks anyway for taking the time to download it and work on helping me out.